# how to find the middle elements of sub matrices in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix and i want to consider it has `4 sub matrices` which are placed together. How can I find the middle element of each sub matrix when they are together?

consider the matrix below. It is built by 4 sub matrices.

```
1  2  3  4   5  6   
7  8  9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36
```

I want to get their middle elements so i could have:

```
 8, 11, 26, 29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have understood this might work for you and this is a demo, so use your own parameters -

**Code**

```
%%// Input matrix 
A = rand(44,44);

%%/ Number of submatrices needed
num_submat = 16;%%// 4 for your example case

%%/ Number of submatrices along row and column
num_submat1= sqrt(num_submat);

%%// Middle element indices along each direction
v1 = floor(size(A,2)/(2*num_submat1))+1:size(A,2)/(num_submat1):size(A,2);

%%// Middle elements
middle_ele = A(v1,v1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always helpful to know that matrix indexing in matlab goes columnwise eg,

```
indOrd = [1,4,7;2,5,8;3,6,9]
```

where the number is the index order and not related to your example. `indOrd(4)` would return 4. Try to use this to find the index locations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each submatrix has odd size `2n+1`, the coordinates of the center of one submatrix alone are `[n+1, n+1]`. If your have a square with M*M submatrices (M=2 in your case), the coordinates are `[n+1+i*(2*n+1), n+1+j*(2*n+1)]`, i and j taken independently in the range `0:M-1`.

Turning back to Matlab, it is now quite easy to generate all indices of the centers of the submatrices grouped in the matrix A:

```
n = floor(size(A,1)/(2*M));
xc = n+1+reshape(repmat(0:M-1,M,1),[],1);
yc = n+1+reshape(repmat((0:M-1)',1,M),[],1);
centers = A(yc, xc);
```

For even-sized submatrix, you have to choose which element is the center, the modification is quite easy to do then.